# Getting Capybara::DriverNotFoundError when trying to run Cucumber tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm getting this error when I run the cucumber tests. Everything seemed to be working fine the previous day but I can't figure out why it stopped working. I was trying to get capybara webkit working and I had changed a couple of files but I don't see why it should affect my tests. Any idea on how to fix this error I'm getting while running the cucumber tests?

Capybara::DriverNotFoundError: no driver called :rack was found, available drivers: :rack_test, :selenium, :webkit, :webkit_debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that you edited many files. Could it be that you didn't revert all the changes you made? I think Capybara would pick the 'rack_test' driver by default, and your system could not find the 'rack' driver.

Since you're doing Cucumber testing, you must have a file called 'env.rb' under the features/support folder. Make sure you don't force 'rack' as your Capybara driver, and your tests should run fine.